# How can I to turn a table inside a table into a colspan?

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have a table generated inside another table. This is generated via Java (I do not touch the system code). My work is in frontend for this.

I need to turn it in colspan using jQuery. See my code here:

```
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" id="accounts-widget" role="grid" style="width: 100%;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr color="#ccc" role="row"><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 246.75px;">Account (unit of measurement)</th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 312.75px;">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td colspan="2">Monthly limit</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Notification threshold</td>
                            <td>Alert threshold</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 104.75px;">Balance</th><th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 56px;">Report</th></tr>
        </thead>




            <tbody>

      <tr role="row" class="odd">
        <td tabindex="0">Dirham (Dirham)</td>
        <td>
          <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td tabindex="0">0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td>2736761539.63</td>
        <td>
                <a href="reportParams.do?serviceId=1" class="btnlink">View</a>
         </td>
      </tr></tbody>




            <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>SSP Extra (Litre)</td>
        <td>
          <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>
                <a href="reportParams.do?serviceId=3" class="btnlink">View</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>




            <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Service (Dinar)</td>
        <td>
          <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>
                <a href="reportParams.do?serviceId=7" class="btnlink">View</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>




            <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Beer (Litres)</td>
        <td>
          <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody></table>
        </td>
        <td>0.00</td>
        <td>
                <a href="reportParams.do?serviceId=10" class="btnlink">View</a>
         </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
```

Comment: Your code has to be in question itself

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question.
Great questions tend to provide quick, great answers from the community

Comment: turn it in colspan?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: The child Table and all your elements needs to turn in <td colspan="x-child-elements">elements</td>

I wish to perform this using jquery

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you are asking, but the code below find a table within a table, and find the parent td, and add colspan to that td.  hope it help.

```js
$('table table').parent('td').attr('colspan',2);
```

```css
table, tr, td {
     border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>table 2</td>
                    <td>table 2</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td>
          
        <td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hummm... thank you.... I will add this code and implement a way to change child table to retrieve only content inside.
In the next hours I will post here the results...

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use a colspan?

I think that your code could be cleaner if you were trying to get to the following result:

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" id="accounts-widget" role="grid" style="width: 100%;" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr color="#ccc" role="row">
                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 246.75px;">Account (unit of measurement)</th>
                <th>Notification threshold (monthly limit)</th>
                <th>Alert threshold (monthly limit)</th>
                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 104.75px;">Balance</th>
                <th class="sorting_disabled" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 56px;">Report</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            
            
        <tbody>
            
            <tr role="row" class="odd">
                <td tabindex="0">Dirham (Dirham)</td>
                <td tabindex="0">0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>2736761539.63</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="reportParams.do?serviceId=1" class="btnlink">View</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
                
            <tr>
                <td>SSP Extra (Litre)</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>                
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="reportParams.do?serviceId=3" class="btnlink">View</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
                
            <tr>
                <td>Service (Dinar)</td>
                    
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="reportParams.do?serviceId=7" class="btnlink">View</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
                
            <tr>
                <td>Beer (Litres)</td>
                    
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>0.00</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="reportParams.do?serviceId=10" class="btnlink">View</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
            
    </table>
```

The steps to achieve that goal are:

- Manually write all the headers of your table (if you cannot change the code you are getting via the backend Java, otherwise change it directly there). You can do this using Jquery by selecting the whole `<thead>` tag and writing your new `<tr><th>...</th><th>..</th></tr>` inside it.
- Select the tables inside the main table. Loop through them and get only the tds. Replace the whole `<table>` (that are inside your main table) by the `<td>...</td>` you have just extracted.
- Get rid of the unnecessary `<tbody>` closing and opening within the main table.

Comment: Yes, I know this... my dificult is to no touch the code... I need to change table inside table to totally TD COLSPAN 
At this way:
<table> inside <table> needs to disappear
child <td> needs to disappear
{content of td} needs to show it
parent <td> needs to be colspan="nº-of-td-childs"